# drupal 7 automatically create and populate a field reference per node after node creation

Tags: nodes

How can I automatically create multiple nodes (content type B) after creating the node (content type A), and then there was a relationship to the nodes (content type B) to the node (content type A)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the following module

[**Autocreate Node Reference**](https://drupal.org/project/autocreate)

> Autocreate Node Reference adds a node reference field and
>   automatically creates the referred node by cloning a template node.